# Losing the input stream in Apache tika

Tags: apache-tika

I am getting the Input  stream from the HttpRequest and using same input stream to extract the metadata. like as shown below.

```
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);

--- more lines for the iteration and getting the stream ------
InputStream input = item.openStream();
```

---

This input is getting passed to the parser as below

```
public Map<String, String> extractMetadata(InputStream is) {

    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    ContentHandler contentHandler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();


        Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();
        parseContext.set(Parser.class ,
                new ParserDecorator(parser));

    try {
        TikaInputStream tikaInputStream = TikaInputStream.get(is);
        parser.parse(tikaInputStream, contentHandler, metadata,parseContext);


    for (String name : metadata.names()) {
            map.put(name ,metadata.get(name));
        }

    } catch (IOException|SAXException|TikaException e) {
        map.put("ERROR","Error while retriving Metadata");
    }

    return  map;
}
```

But when I try to get the input stream then it is not same as if i dont use tika for extract.
Does Tika Dirty the stream ?

Comment: I have now cloned the input stream thus having duplicate stream to get the  work done. somehow feel this is not right. May be I can only clone the header so that i get the metadata

Comment: May be its ok as i opened the stream read the metadata and closed the stream. Its not open for very long time. but still there is a phase where there are two stream open in the application may be for short duration.

Comment: Well, of course the input stream is "changed" in that way that data is read from it. This data is then not available through the stream anymore. From a general input stream, all data can be read only once.